# how to fill text color with the same preload image color in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to set/fill my text(avg 450 words) color with the same color of preload image to my canvas in P5js / JS. Is anybody can help me with how to do that?

Comment: Cross posted on processing discourse: https://discourse.processing.org/t/fill-text-color-with-the-same-color-of-preload-image/32716 (please mention when you crosspost).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the same color of preload image." Does the image contain a single solid color? It would be helpful if you would share the code you have so far, even if it isn't working. It is important to demonstrate that you've made an effort, and if possible include a minimal, reproducible example of the problem or question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the colour of an image and then `fill` with that colour so the text will be the same colour.

Here's a link to [the documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get) for the `get()` method which is what you're looking for.

In order to do this, we use the `get(x, y)` method to get the pixel at a specific location, this returns us an RGBA value which we can use to fill.

I've put together a really simple example to demonstrate this:

```js
let img;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage('img.jpg');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  image(img, 0, 0);
  let c = get(0, 0);
  fill(c);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  image(img, 0, 0);
  textSize(20);
  text('I am the same colour', 100, 350);
}
```

I'm just grabbing the very first pixel and filling with that. Here's a link to a [p5.js sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/codeheir/sketches/FfvZXXDKJ) so you can see it running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In theory, when using a long text, could I separate the letters or words in the text and make the color of the pixels they come across in the image? Also, I can divide the text into rows and columns with the same dimensions as the image and redraw the image with the text?

Comment: yeah you could definitely do this, you may want to have each letter in its own `text()` method and above it have the respected colour.